# AWS QuickSight: maxOver() calculated field?

Tags: sql, amazon-quicksight

I am a stock trader who visualizes data in QuickSight. I identify the trades I want to submit to the market, sometimes for the same stock, at the same time, but in opposite directions depending on the price of the stock at that time. See below for an example of trades I might identify for 1/19/22 0800:

| Date | Hour | Stock | Direction | Price | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/19/22 | 0800 | Apple | BUY | $10 | 2 |
| 1/19/22 | 0800 | Apple | SELL | $20 | 1 |
| 1/19/22 | 0800 | Microsoft | BUY | $15 | 3 |

Using QuickSight, I want to visualize (in pivot tables and charts) the volume that I trade, using the **maximum possible trade volume**. For example, QuickSight simply sums the `Volume` column to `6`, when really I want it to sum to `5`, because the max possible trade volume for that hour is `5` (the Apple trades in the example are mutually exclusive, because the stock price cannot be both beneath $10, triggering a `BUY`, and above $20, triggering a `SELL` at the same date-time. Therefore, I want the day's traded volume to reflect the MAX possible volume I could have traded (2+3)).

I have used the maxOver() function as so: `maxOver({volume}, [{stock}, {date}, {hour}], PRE_AGG)`, but I would like to view my trade volume rolled up to the day as so:

| Date | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| 1/19 | 5 |

Is there a way to do this using QuickSight calculated fields? Should this aggregation be done with a SQL custom field?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new calculated field called
**volume_direction_specifier**

```
  {Volume} * 10 + ifelse({Direction}='BUY', 1, 2)
```

This is a single number that will indicate the direction and volume. (this is needed in cases where the max possible volume is the same for both the BUY and SELL entries within the same hour).

Then compute the maxOver on this new field in a calculated field called **max_volume_direction_specifier**

```
maxOver({volume_direction_specifier}, [{stock}, {date}, {hour}], PRE_AGG)
```

Add a new field which will give the Volume for rows that have the max `volume_direction_specifier` per hour
**volume_for_max_trade_volume_per_hour**

```
ifelse(volume_direction_specifier = max_volume_direction_specifier, {volume}, null)
```

And finally, you should be able to add `volume_for_max_trade_volume_per_hour` to your table (grouped by day) and its SUM will give the **maximum possible trade volume** per day.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment! I just edited my post to make this more clear, but the issue is not the directionality of the trade itself, it is the mutual exclusivity of BUY and SELL trades in the same date-hour. Because only one can possibly be executed, I want to know the sum of the MAX possible volume traded.

Comment: Updated my reply